# Safely uninstall avfs

Tags: uninstall, avfs

I installed [avfs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/avf/) to check how it works. It works, but after a short test drive I decided to uninstall the package, basically because I can change files within a zip but it's not possible to write them back.

Now my question is, at this point is it safe to completely uninstall avfs?

```
$ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove avfs
```

I ask that because I see that a new "virtual" directory `~/.avfs` has been created with a mirror of my disk. For this reason I wonder which is the right procedure to uninstall **without compromising any data**.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be safe? Obviously removing a package isn't going to remove data that doesn't belong to it.

Comment: @Gilles Cause my ignorance initially it was not obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My doubt was justified because of the lack of docs about avfs. Anyway, it was enough to umount the virtual fs

```
$ umountavfs
```

and uninstall the package the usual way.